# Tally Ledger Voucher XML Export

Tags: xml, soap, request

I am trying to get Tally Erp 9 Ledger through XML Request  , everything is working fine except date range if set From date to 1-Apr-2015 and To date to 30-Apr-2015 i get the data for Apr Month but if change To date to 31-May-2015 I get only May month data whereas i want two months  data pls help...

```
<ENVELOPE>
<HEADER>
<TALLYREQUEST>Export Data</TALLYREQUEST>
</HEADER>
<BODY>
<EXPORTDATA>
<REQUESTDESC>
<REPORTNAME>Ledger Vouchers</REPORTNAME>
<STATICVARIABLES>
<SVCURRENTCOMPANY>Demo Company</SVCURRENTCOMPANY>
<SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
<SVFROMDATE>01-Apr-2015</SVFROMDATE>
<SVTODATE>31-May-2015</SVTODATE
<LEDGERNAME>My Ledger</LEDGERNAME>
</STATICVARIABLES>
</REQUESTDESC>
</EXPORTDATA>
</BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ENVELOPE>
<HEADER>
        <VERSION>1</VERSION>
        <TALLYREQUEST>Export</TALLYREQUEST>
        <TYPE>Data</TYPE>
        <ID>Trial Balance</ID>
</HEADER>
<BODY>
<DESC>
<STATICVARIABLES>
                    <EXPLODEFLAG>Yes</EXPLODEFLAG>
                    <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
        </STATICVARIABLES>
</DESC>
</BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, only change to make is a closing tag '>' to the "SVTODATE" field.

```
<ENVELOPE>
<HEADER>
<TALLYREQUEST>Export Data</TALLYREQUEST>
</HEADER>
<BODY>
<EXPORTDATA>
<REQUESTDESC>
<REPORTNAME>Ledger Vouchers</REPORTNAME>
<STATICVARIABLES>
<SVCURRENTCOMPANY>Demo Company</SVCURRENTCOMPANY>
<SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
<SVFROMDATE>01-Apr-2018</SVFROMDATE>
<SVTODATE>31-May-2018</SVTODATE>
<LEDGERNAME>My Ledger</LEDGERNAME>
</STATICVARIABLES>
</REQUESTDESC>
</EXPORTDATA>
</BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

Comment: This is rather than a comment instead of posting as an answer to the question.

Comment: I've edited the answer to include the full request.

Comment: @MitaleeRao it seems u have worked with tally integration .  I went through document and develpor's doc too but still finding myslef confused. Can you please help me how to get all companies from tally?

Comment: @ShivamTrivedi: You will not be able to get all the companies in a user's Tally application - only the ones that are loaded. However it doesn't seem to be related to this question. Can you open a new one? I'd be happy to help out.

Comment: well i am not intrested in opening a new one as i am doing R&D for that. I have developed a php software and now want to make modules to work with tally. I am not finding any good resource where i can get a tag list for different reports. If u got any please help. Thankyou for your response btw.

Comment: @ShivamTrivedi: Please see my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57830746/2048229) - what you asked is a big topic!

Answer (score -1):

```
<ENVELOPE>
<HEADER>        
<TALLYREQUEST>Export Data</TALLYREQUEST>        
</HEADER>
<BODY>
<EXPORTDATA>
<REQUESTDESC>
<REPORTNAME>Daybook</REPORTNAME>
<STATICVARIABLES>
<SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT> 
<EXPLODEFLAG>Yes</EXPLODEFLAG>          
</STATICVARIABLES>                  
</REQUESTDESC>      
</EXPORTDATA>                                
</BODY>                                
</ENVELOPE>
```

Comment: This is no way related to the questrion.